# Remote ssh vscode: bind: Address already in use channel_setup_fwd_listener: cannot listen to port

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, ssh-keys, ssh-tunnel, vscode-remote-ssh

I want to remote connect to linux from my Windows 10 using remote ssh extension of vs code.
But these errors occured in terminal of vscode while connecting and vscoderemote ssh extension hangs:
`

- Bind[127.0.0.1]: Address already in use
- channel_setup_fwd_listener: cannot listen to port: 58000
- Could not request local forwarding.
  `

I tried these methods:

- deleted .vscode-server folder in linux;
- deleted .ssh in users folder of windows;
- killed vscode server
  ... and reconnected through remote ssh extension of vscode.

Anyway these errors occuring:
`

- Bind[127.0.0.1]: Address already in use
- channel_setup_fwd_listener: cannot listen to port: 58000
- Could not request local forwarding.
  `
  Please help.

Comment: You seem to be connecting via SSH tunnel, but you didn't tell us anything about it.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl What should I tell You? I exxplained all procedures that I did. But there are errors above. Please help